# stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused. Laravel 5.7 dump server

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5.7, php-7.2

I'm using Laravel. When I dd($request->all()) that the data inside it involves file (.mp3 file). It returns the error:

```
[2019-03-16 15:44:12] local.ERROR: stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused at /vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Server/Connection.php:63
```

Can this be a problem with php-fpm ? If I run php artisan serve, this does not happen, and if I run php artisan dump server it does not happen either.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 9):

Finally I figured out. The problem was that the `upload_max_filesize` in the `php.ini` of the php-fpm, it was only 2M, after increasing to 100M it works.
So you must change this value in:

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

upload_max_filesize=100M
```

And ofcourse this value must be the same also

```
upload_max_filesize=100M
```

Comment: then if you have nginx and php-fpm
service php7.2-fpm restart
service nginx restart

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nginx(although only the structure are different) but in apache 2.4.6 I added this to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot /home/yoursite/public_html/public
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000/public/index.php"
```

and in `/etc/php-fpm.d` I have:

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
chroot = /home/yoursite/public_html
chdir = /public
```

and lastly don't forget to restart both apache and php-fpm each time you change something in `httpd.conf` or `php-fpm.d` files. Again because I was using apache I had these commands in centos 7:

```
systemctl restart httpd && systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem persist )=