# Laravel Gives error While uploading Video

Tags: laravel

```php
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
  $file = $request->file->store('public/upload');
}
dd($request->all());
```

while uploading image it response the dd request but while uploading video it gives error file failed to upload or sometimes

> stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused

I have change the php.ini file but still, the error is the same

Comment: look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203433/stream-socket-sendto-connection-refused-laravel-5-7-dump-server

Comment: what's the size of your video file ? have you tried with a smaller example? What are the attributes you changed in php.ini ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stream\_socket\_sendto(): Connection refused. Laravel 5.7 dump server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203433/stream-socket-sendto-connection-refused-laravel-5-7-dump-server)

Answer (score 0):

I have also uploading videos in laravel and used below code without getting error, Please use below code if its help you

```
$custom_file_name = "";
if (isset($request->file) && !empty($request->file)) {
    $errors     = array();
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $resume_file_ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $custom_file_name = "file_".time().".".$resume_file_ext;
    $file_upload_dir  = public_path() . '/file/';

    $file->move($file_upload_dir, $custom_file_name);  

    return $custom_file_name
}
```

Comment: still the same error @manojPatel and by using this script the error is exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).",

Comment: i have change php.ini file and php.ini-pre1.7.and use command to recognize the ini file php -i | grep php.ini
but the errors is same

Comment: In my php.ini file i have same settings upload_max_filesize = 2M and its working fine, Can you please let me know your laravel and php version?